# Adding a indoor concrete ramp to existing concrete

Tags: concrete, flooding

My plan is to build a mold (by building a shallow wooden box, made to support putting a sheet of aluminum inside to create the curve) and fill it (upside down of course) with concrete to create what is shown in this image:

[image]
The idea is to install it (flat side down) in a doorway, adhering it to the existing concrete floor as well as filling in any gaps on the sides between the ramp and the doorway with concrete (the walls are stone covered in concrete). 
The purpose being to stop any water from flooding from one part of our basement (laundry room) to the other (where we have our home theater)
Any advice would be very helpful as every part of this process is pretty new to me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: how are you stopping water outside of doorway?   Water is pretty good at going somewhere.   Also why isn't your concrete sloped towards your laundry room?

Comment: Not sure why it's not sloped, and to do that would be an enormous job when the only real place it needs to be sloped is the doorway. The flooding has never gotten higher than about an inch, so I'm thinking as long as this "ramp" is a few inches high, and I seal it up on the bottom and sides between the doorway, water shouldn't get through...

Comment: What about water getting under the bottom plate of the walls that separate the rooms ?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, your laundry room connects to another room with basically a smooth level concrete floor.... and you want to create a "lip" in the doorway to prevent water escaping the laundry room.

To state the obvious:  the real trick would be to prevent the flooding in the first place.  Why does it flood?  Is there a drain that could be improved?

Aside from that, let's turn the conversation around.  What you're describing is kinda like a very low shower-stall enclosure.  If you can shift your thinking to 'how would I make a 1-inch lip to enclose a shower', you might start thinking about other options:

- something made of tile (grouting into place to get a good seal on the sides and bottom)
- some plastic pre-made shower seal that might be cut to length (link: [https://www.amazon.com/Wide-High-Acrylic-Frameless-Threshold/dp/B0031Q4DF8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0031Q4DF8) )
- even enclose the 'flooding area' (like a washing machine) with a water-catchment basin (like many people do for water heaters) might be a solution

Hopefully this is of some use to you.  Good luck!